# Не работает интерпретатор для OpenCV Pycharm

Tags: python, opencv

Хотел использовать библиотеку OpenCV `cv2`, код, написанный при помощи библиотеки работает, а подсказок к коду нет, использую последнюю версию `PyCharm Community`, переустанавливал `PyCharm`, `Python`, не помогло. Пытался изменить интерпретатор на `cv2`, не помогло.